# how to get seesion in page.js file in next 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am not able to get session data to call API on page
in next 12 > getsession(")was working
in next 13 > ??
tried these two methods and getting initial data
getsession()
usesession()

Answer (score 0):

in next js 13 version a new method is ad getserversession()
we can now use this method
how t house
call getserversession(authO)
here authO is a function which we have create in next auth and exported